# How does a cache actually store data in the "offset"?

Tags: c#, caching, cpu-architecture

So for my computer architecture class I have to simulate a cache/memory relationship on C# and I'm just not sure how a cache actually stores data. I get the concept of a cache tag, but I really don't get the offset.

So say I have an RAM that holds 256 32bit integers. I want to have a caching system where I have a cache that holds 8 32bit integers. But then in those 32bit integers in the cache I need to add the tag and valid bit, which makes it roughly sized down to 26 bits or so. So how can I store the 32 bit data in that remaining 26 bits?

Here is the code I have right now, it's still a work in progress

```
class Memory
{
    public List<UInt32> instructions = new List<UInt32>();

    const int directCacheSize = 8;
    ulong[] directCache = new ulong[directCacheSize];

    private int[] stack = new int[256];

    public int this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            int directMapIndex = i % directCacheSize;
            if (directCache[directMapIndex] == Convert.ToUInt64(stack[i]))
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(directCache[directMapIndex] - 18446744069414584320);
            }
            else
            {
                directCache[directMapIndex] = (Convert.ToUInt64(i) << 32) + Convert.ToUInt64(stack[i]);
                return stack[i];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            stack[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding the question. The cache doesn't store the data in the offset; the cache stores the data in the data block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been trying to understand this mostly incoherent question and I think I've got it.

I was thinking originally that your fundamental error is that bits used to maintain the cache data structure bits are subtracted from the data size; that doesn't make any sense. They are *added* to the data size.

But then I realized that no, your *fundamental* error is that you have confused bits with bytes. You are **subtracting** six **bits** from 32 **bytes** to nonsensically get 26, but you should be **adding** six bits to 32 x 8 **bits**.

The error that is just plain confusing is that you also seem to have confused the offset into the data block with the data block itself. The data block stores the data. **The offset identifies the location of the relevant data within the data block.** The offset is part of an *effective address*, not a *cache line*!

You also seem to have forgotten about the dirty bit throughout.

> So then a single block in my direct map cache would look like this: [tag 5bit][data 32bit]

No. The number of times that 32 appears in this problem has confused you deeply:

- eight 32 bit words is 32 bytes
- five bits can represent 32 possible tags
- If you have 32 tags and 1024 bytes then each tag identifies 32 bytes

That's a lot of 32s and you've confused them terribly.

Start over.

Suppose you want a single line with 8 32 bit words in it, for a total of 32 bytes. What has to be in the single cache line?

- the 32 bytes -- NOT BITS
- a tag identifying where the 32 bytes came from
- one validity bit
- one dirty bit

If we assume that the 32 bytes can only be on 32-byte boundaries, and there are 1024 / 32 = 32 such boundaries, then for the tag we need log2(32) = 5 bits, so the total cache line size would be:

- 32 bytes **NOT BITS** of data
- 5 bits of tag
- one validity bit
- one dirty bit

Make sense?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question and sorry if its worded weirdly. So for my example I would have to change that 26 bit to a 32 bit?

So then a single block in my direct map cache would look like this:

**[tag 5bit][data                      32bit]**?

Comment: @KeithYong: No. I finally see why you are confused. You have mixed up bits with bytes. I'll add more to my answer.

Comment: @KeithYong: Your question reminds me of the famous puzzle: three people share a $300 hotel room, each paying $100 cash. The manager realizes that he has overcharged; the room is only $250. The manager sends the bellboy up to the room with five tens. The bellboy decides to keep $20 and gives a $10 to each person. So each person paid $90, times three is $270 and the bellboy kept $20, so that's $290 accounted for. Where is the missing $10 bill?

Comment: Ok I see the error now, but I'm still confused at other things about cache. So if I want to store a single 32 bit integer into say Block #1 of the cache where would I put it inside the block? Is it that the block would be able to hold many 32 bit integers for usage? So, maybe it'll look like **[tag 5bit][data 32bit][tag 5bit][data 32bit] ... [tag 5bit][data 32bit]**?

Comment: @KeithYong: I don't understand the question. Are you now supposing that there are multiple lines in the cache, each storing a single 4 byte data block? In that case you're going to need an eight bit tag; do you see why?

Comment: I'm supposing that each block in a cache would be able to store many integers until it reaches the 256 bit limit. So block 1 would store say 3 integers, block 2 would store 1 integer, block 3 would store 5 integers, and so on

Comment: @KeithYong: You are very very confused about how a processor cache works; I'm not sure if I can unconfuse you in a short comment and not much time. A processor cache is a collection of cache lines. Each cache line contains a copy of a portion of main memory, called the data block. Each data block is of the same size. If you have eight cache lines and each one contains four bytes then each one contains four bytes from one particular region of main memory, not one byte from here and another byte from there.

Comment: The point of having multiple cache lines is that you can have memory from multiple locations. You never store data from disparate locations in the same cache line. I would talk to your professor or TA or fellow students and get someone to explain the whole thing to you again from the top.

Comment: Yeah I've been scouring youtube on tutorials and all of them have left unanswered questions. I will just ask my professor to explain it in person, thanks for your time. Also do you have any recommended tutorials or readings on the internet about this topic?